# System.Globalization.SortVersion Exception in XamarinStudio

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, monodevelop

I have a project built in the Mac version of Xamarin.I'm trying to run it on Windows version of Xamarin Studio.But I keep getting

> System.Globalization.SortVersion Exception

Seems like this is a unfixed bug in Xamarin.The workaround suggested in some forums is to disable `MS-BUILD` ,I did after that" keep getting this exception and the app crashes.

> Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "xamarin"

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pinta/OCs2AzAxQek) some variant.

If you recently did anything related with addin - you should try to wipe out the addin cach. It locates in `AppData/Roaming/mono.addins`

Hm. About `DllNotFoundException` it looks like this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8309)

The file "etc\mono\config" in installation directory contains a wrong dll
mapping:

```
<dllmap dll="ggdiplus" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
<dllmap dll="ggdiplus.dll" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
```

This results in a `DllNotFoundException` while starting applications which
utilize `System.Drawing`.

For Windows, this problem can be solved by removing the entries from config
file.

Comment: Thanks but  there is no folder named mono.addins in my system.

Comment: Do you get this error when compile or when program started?

Comment: When compiling.i pressed the resume button after that the app crashed with some critical error.

Comment: I tried downgrading to the the first release of xamarin studio-5.9.It does not work as well.Seems like we need more time to get around the bugs in the ide that to code :) .Tons of bugs in this IDE :)

Comment: sorry the build is complete .. it happens when running.

Comment: Can you debug code and find the line where it happens?

Comment: System.Drawing.Color ccolor=System.Drawing.Color.White; -- > Its saying type initiation exception.

Comment: Since the exe if created i tried running it from outside using mono command line.It does not run,but no errors.

Comment: ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so